# Know CentOS7 IP address

Tags: centos, ip-address, centos7

I just installed CentOS on my VM, I want to know his IP address to be able to connect.

When I'm doing `ip addr`:

I get this:

```
[root@localhost]# ip addr
1: lo:  <LOOPBACK, UP, LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST, MULTICAST, UP, LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
link/ether 42:01:0a:f0:7e:a4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

My IP address is not displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

make sure your system connect with network

```
# ip address show
OR SIMPLY
# ip a s
```

However, it is still possible to use the old-fashioned `ifconfig` command. Thus our objective is to install ifconfig on CentOS 7 Linux which is a part of net-tools package.

Comment: I get the same thing as `ip addr`. My IP address 192.168.0.x is not displayed.

Comment: which version of centos using ?

Comment: I use the version CentOS7.

Comment: Thnaks that's it :)